# firestore array-like data structure indexing limitation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the firestore documentation, there is a description below

> Indexing limits - A single document can have only 20,000 properties in
>   order to use Cloud Firestore built-in indexes. If your array-like data
>   structure grows to tens of thousands of members, you may run into this
>   limit.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/arrays

I want to know how I can interpret the description.
Which of two patterns meet the limitation?

```
<pattern 1: categories in one document above 20,000> 
    doc1
     - id:111  
     - categories: {aaaa:true, aaab:false, aaac:true, aaad: false, aaae:true, aaaf:true, aaag:true, aaah:true, aaai:true, aaaj:true, ,,,,,,,,,,, }
```

another pattern

```
<pattern 2:  categories in one document is a few but as a collection of document number of categories above 20,000> 
    doc_1
    - id:111
    categories{aaaa:true, aaab:false, aaac:true, only several element}
    doc_2
    - id:111
    categories{aaad:true, aaae:false, aaaf:true, only several element}
    doc_3
    - id:111
    categories{aaag:true, aaah:false, aaai:true, only several element}
```

I believe that pattern 1 reach the limit, but is pattern 2 reach the limit?

Answer (score 2):

The limit is on the **total** number of properties, so it's possible that both patterns could hit the 20,000 limit.

Here are some examples of counting properties that may help:

This document has two properties: `a` and `b.c`

```
{
  a: "foo",
  b: {
   c: "bar"
  }
}
```

This document has four properties: `a`, `b`, `b.c`, `d`

```
{
  a: "foo",
  b: {
   c: "bar",
  },
  d: ["quz", "qaz"]
}
```

And this document has four as well:

```
{
  a: "foo",
  b: {
   c: "bar",
  },
  d: ["quz", "qaz", "apple", "banana"]
}
```

This document has five:

```
{
  a: "foo",
  b: {
   c: "bar",
  },
  d: ["quz", "qaz"],
  e: ["apple", "banana"]
}
```

So it's not about the length of any single array or how deeply nested things are, it's about the total number of queryable values.

---

**EDIT 03/05/18**: I was wrong before when I said that array members counted separately against the index.  They do not, that was something we had in place when Firestore was in Alpha that never applied in a public release.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
Then the limit is applied to the number of leaf-node.
If the documents exists as collection, number does not related to the collection but only applied to each document.

Comment: ```{
  a: "foo",
  b: {
   c: "bar",
  },
  d: [{"x":"quz", "m":"qaz"}]
}``` according to this. above document also contains only 4 fileds. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct, objects within arrays are not indexed.